# Interfacing with a C64 SID Chip (clone)

Tags: stm32, clock

I bought a MOS 6582 clone and want to control it with a STM32 Nucleo. Basically make a simple MIDI controlled synth. The hookup looks simple, but have a control question. Here's the detail on the clock input pin:

> 02 (Pin 6) — This TTL-level input is the master clock for SID. All oscillator frequencies and envelope rates are referenced to this clock. 02 also controls data transfers between SID and the microprocessor. Data can only be transferred when 02 is high. Essentially, 02 acts as a high-active chip select as far as data transfers are concerned. This pin is normally connected to the system clock, with a nominal operating frequency of 1.0 MHz.

I was going to use the Arduino framework for STM32, but not sure if it is possible to do what I need.

I don't think there is a problem generating a 1MHz clock, but I have to toggle the address/data lines when the clock pulse is high.

Is there a way to do that with the Arduino framework, or do I need to use straight STM32 HAL and some sort of interrupt?

The data/address pins are going to be changing at a much lower rate than the 1MHz clock - probably in the low KHz range, if that matters.

Here's a block diagram:

[image]

Comment: _"I don't think there is a problem generating a 1MHz clock"_ - How do you intend to generate the 1MHz clock?

Comment: Generating the master clock won't be a problem.

However the master clock also defines a bus cycle so writing to the chip must happen in one master clock. You don't say which STM32 you will be using, but some of them support synchronous external buses via FSMC or similar peripheral. Please state which exact STM32 model you will be using.

Comment: It is a STM32L432KC.  However, I can get another dev board if needed that has the proper peripheral

Comment: IMO you could try FSMC, but it would turn the STM32 to work slow as Commodore 64.  It would be almost impossible to have an Arduino compatible GUI, it's a challenge even for native HAL to interface this chip, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You could configure a DMA channel to write to or read from a GPIO port - maybe a pair of them if you need to manipulate both the Data and Address lines. Trigger the DMA from either the same timer which generates the 1MHz 'bus' clock, or use a different timer with an offset if you need the data transfer to be 'out of phase' with the bus clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FSMC SRAM - Read

[image]

CID Read:

[image]

```
ADDSET+DATAST > 238ns
```

FSMC SRAM Write:

[image]

CID Write:

[image]

```
DATAST > 350ns


NOE = Output Enable
NEx = CS
NWE = RW
```

Since you need a kind of level shifter, you could also use a bi-directional latch for that. The SID has only R/W signal to determine the direction of databus. Somehow I think this could be problematic, so you can hook up a latch controlled by NOE signal.

Since this is asynchronous access type, you have to choose the correct HCLK for your application, then determine the timing with the use of HCLK periods. You set up one TIMx timer 1 MHz with interrupt at rising clock. At interrupt you write or read a single byte from SRAM FSMC. In that way you could have a synchronized write/read with the PHI clock.

Comment: Thanks will review this